# Is there an official Concourse pipeline grammar?

Tags: grammar, pipeline, intellij-plugin, concourse

I couldn't find it online after a little bit of searching, so i'm asking it here. Is there a 'reference' bnf grammar file for yaml file of concourse's pipeline ? As a side project, I'm trying to create an IntelliJ plugin that could do syntax highlight and auto completion for CI/CD Concourse pipelines, and would try to avoid manually retyping all that grammar to minimize error risk and time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a "grammar file" - the types are defined in code. For example, the top level pipeline is defined [here](https://github.com/concourse/concourse/blob/b700f2dcf58e21003a7cad3794badd0deeac59bf/atc/config.go#L22-L27) as:

```
type Config struct {
    Groups        GroupConfigs    `yaml:"groups" json:"groups" mapstructure:"groups"`
    Resources     ResourceConfigs `yaml:"resources" json:"resources" mapstructure:"resources"`
    ResourceTypes ResourceTypes   `yaml:"resource_types" json:"resource_types" mapstructure:"resource_types"`
    Jobs          JobConfigs      `yaml:"jobs" json:"jobs" mapstructure:"jobs"`
}
```

The [`atc.Config.Validate()`](https://github.com/concourse/concourse/blob/b700f2dcf58e21003a7cad3794badd0deeac59bf/fly/commands/internal/validatepipelinehelpers/validate.go#L12) command is also based on code - not an external grammar.

You could probably reason through those source files to determine the structure. It *might* be possible to [generate a jsonschema from the go types](https://github.com/alecthomas/jsonschema) and then use that.